# How to apply ease-in-out after cursor moves away?

Tags: html, css

I have 6 images all applied with the ease-in-out css. When the image is hovered on the code works flawlessly. However since it is only applied as a hover and not the whole elelment it just stops working. So it will only ease-in. Wondering how to get it to ease-out as well. Thanks! To see in action go [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kktnuesd/)

CSS

```
.img {
        float: left;
}
    #center:hover{
position: relative;
        opacity: 0.5;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .4 ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .4 ease-in-out;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="center">
        <a href="https://www.netatlantic.com/resources/industries/agencies?utm_source=netatlantic&utm_medium=web_homepage&utm_campaign=vertical&utm_content=agencies"><img id="center" src="featuredindustries/img/1.png" style="float:left; padding-left: 0px; margin: auto;" hspace="00px" alt="thumbnail1" width="311" height="311" float="left" longdesc="Ad Agencies"/></a>

        <a href="https://www.netatlantic.com/resources/industries/high-volume-senders?utm_source=netatlantic&utm_medium=web_homepage&utm_campaign=vertical&utm_content=high-volume-senders"><img src="featuredindustries/img/2.png" alt="thumbnail2" name="center" width="311" height="311" class="img1" id="center" style="float:left" longdesc="High-Volume Senders" align="left" hspace="0px"/></a>

        <a href="https://www.netatlantic.com/resources/industries/publishing?utm_source=netatlantic&utm_medium=web_homepage&utm_campaign=vertical&utm_content=publishers"><img id="center" src="featuredindustries/img/3.png" style="float:left" hspace="00px" alt="thumbnail1" width="311" height="311" float="left" longdesc="Publishers"/></a>

        </br><a href="https://www.netatlantic.com/resources/industries/politicalcampaigners?utm_source=netatlantic&utm_medium=web_homepage&utm_campaign=vertical&utm_content=political"><img src="featuredindustries/img/4.png" alt="thumbnail1" name="center" width="311" height="311" id="center" style="float:left; padding-left: 0px; margin: auto; display: block;" longdesc="Political Senders" hspace="00px" float="left"/></a> 

        <a href="https://www.netatlantic.com/resources/industries/leadcapture?utm_source=netatlantic&utm_medium=web_homepage&utm_campaign=vertical&utm_content=leadcapture"><img id="center" src="featuredindustries/img/5.png" style="float:left" hspace="00px" alt="thumbnail1" width="311" height="311" float="left" longdesc="Lead-Capture"/></a>

        <a href="https://www.netatlantic.com/emailmarketing/email-marketing-overview"><img id="center" src="featuredindustries/img/6.png" style="float:left" hspace="00px" alt="thumbnail1" width="311" height="311" float="left" longdesc="Other"/></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this for img (not on hover)

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .4 ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .4 ease-in-out;
transition-timing-function: linear;
```

on hover use only

```
position: relative;
opacity: 0.5;
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason now it does not ease in or out at all. I know it something wrong with my coding but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @SethChouinard can u give me a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry the CSS that I included was incorrect I am going to fix it. It should be #center:hover{ not #center{

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kktnuesd/2/ - fix your fiddle enjoy) u still here?

Comment: Cool, One last thing the shadow seems to already be applied. Anyway to have that show up on the hover as well. The idea is so that it looks like it is coming toward them. Thanks

Comment: You just have to make sure your transition is on the <img> element and then add what you want to happen in the hover state. For a simple example...

Comment: `img {
 transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 31px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}`